# Rule violation penalties: Written warning, Suspension for 7 days, 30 days, 365 days, and then what?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-tools, account-suspension

The system-recommended penalties for repeatedly-occurring serious rule violations on Stack Exchange are:

> 1. Written warning
> 2. 7-day suspension
> 3. 30-day suspension
> 4. 365-day suspension

What comes after the 365-day suspension?  Account deletion?  Network-wide suspension?  What?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That depends, on a lot of factors. You already noted that these are the *recommended* suspension lengths; ♦ moderators can deviate from them and issue shorter suspensions, or go for the maximum length the first or second time already:

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days.

(source: [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/))

People can change a lot in a year, which is why longer suspensions are rare. (Almost) everybody deserves a second/third/fourth chance.

Generally speaking, people's main accounts are not deleted (but sockpuppets might be); it's easier to keep track of them that way. A network-wide suspension can only be issued by Community Managers and are reserved for the most egregious cases.

Comment: (Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333355/user-is-suspended-till-18-but-it-is-2019-and-he-she-is-still-suspended)

Comment: So... apparently, there are plenty of cases where the 4th suspension is shorter than the 3rd (Ex. 365 for 3rd but only 7 for 4th), and this should be normal.  Right?

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya Are there plenty of cases? Yes. Does that make it normal? No. It's still up to the moderator.

Answer (score 10):

I'll add a bit about network-wide suspensions as the other answer explains very well about per-site suspensions.

Network-wide suspensions are issued only when the person violates the rules on more than one site. One might be a total troll on one site and get suspended there consecutively for a year at a time, while being a perfect legit user on other sites.

Also, even when network-wide suspension is issued, it's not a dead end for the user: moderator can lift the suspension of the user per-site. It's rare, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

More of an addendum:

> Account deletion?

Isn't an option at **all** for "real" accounts. You provided your content here, and SE Inc. can't just come in and unilaterally deny you access to your content/profile information.

And because of that, you will find a few users here or there with multi year suspensions.