# User is suspended till '18, but it is 2019 and he/she is still suspended?

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page, account-suspension

Just now I saw a user with a banner on his/her profile page that says the user is suspended until **'18**.  Right now, it is **2019**.  The user should have been set free last year, but for some reason he/she still appears to be suspended with only 1 reputation.

> [image: Suspended till '18, but it's 2019!!!]

Why is the user still appearing to be suspended?  It seems to be a kooky error to me.  Can anyone please try to fix this bug, or at least explain to me what is going on?

-

Comment: Because they are still suspended. That date ends in a different century.

Comment: It's so incredibly rare that the system simply doesn't consider different centuries. It just takes the last two digits of the year. We're talking about like < 10 cases that changing it would even affect.

Comment: @animuson You do realize how public and high-profile those cases tend to be, right?

Comment: @animuson what about not showing a date at all? Those who need to know it (the suspended user and the mod team) already know, others have little use for that detail.

Comment: @animuson why not just end the suspension in 2099 (**'99**)? That way SE avoids any possible confusion and visitors won't think the company either forgets to lift a suspension or they don't even care when a suspension (expulsion) period has expired. Visitors are not going to think that '18 refers to the next century not until we reach something like the year 2050.

Comment: It's a factor of the means of applying a suspension. IIRC, you don't specify a date you specify a period, so mods would have to do maths in order to create the correct time span to apply. S'not worth it.